# WPF ViewModel not active presenter

Tags: wpf, viewmodel, diagram, presenter

There is a ViewModel that consists of some related object (nodes and lines( ,
How it can be possible to display (synchronize) these VM in View and keep object connections.
I use some DataTemplate to map model to view but each object would be synchronized (with powerful binding) to its related object but how can i link (and synchronize) this DataTemplate generated UI element together.
I describe problem from another viewpoint here:
[Sunchronizing view model and view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643912/sunchronizing-view-model-and-view)

Answer (score 0):

To keep your view synchronized you should use bindings, your binding sources need to implement certain interfaces or be dependency properties though. For collections you need to implement [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) and for properties you'd use [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), if you then change the source your view will change as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I did that, mean I implemented  INotifyPropertyChanged in view model. But I want to link generated UI elements to each other, as i describe I generate them with DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Next to implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and using ICollectionChanged (ObservableCollection) and binding to the views, you might consider implementing [IEditableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx) when you want to support the editing of the data.

This interface allows you to undo edit actions. Without implementing IEditableObject you would need to go back to the data source to reset the to the original values when canceling the modifications. The interface is also supported by the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize the VM and View using Relaying Command Logic.

you can see a sample workout here

[Binding the "WindowState" property of a window in WPF using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671368/binding-the-windowstate-property-of-a-window-in-wpf-using-mvvm/4677147#4677147)