# ViewModel Views relation/link/synchronization

Tags: c#, wpf, view, viewmodel

Third try to describing problem:

- Try 1:
  [Sunchronizing view model and view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643912/sunchronizing-view-model-and-view)
- Try2:
  [WPF ViewModel not active presenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698655/wpf-viewmodel-not-active-presenter)
- Try3:

I have some class for view models:

```
public class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Guid NodeId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

public class Connection: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Node StartNode { get; set; }
        public Node EndNode { get; set; }
    }

public class SettingsPackModel
{
        public List<Node> Nodes { get; private set; }
        public List<Connection> Connections { get; private set; }
}
```

I also have some templates to displays these models:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Node}">…</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Connection}">
 <my:ConnectionElment StartNodeElment="???" EndNodeElment="???"> 
</my:ConnectionElment>
<DataTemplate>
```

But the problem is that DataTemplate for Connection need reference  ot two element of type UIElement  , how can I  pass these two, how can I fill ??? in above expression?

**Edit:**
I actually want to hide that's part in this try, but as I describe it there: [Sunchronizing view model and view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643912/sunchronizing-view-model-and-view). I would use something like this :

```
<ItemsControl    ItemsSource="{Binding AllElements}" 
ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ElementThumbVMDataTemplateStyle> 
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel> 
            <ItemsPanelTemplate> 
                <kw:DiagramCanvas /> 
            </ItemsPanelTemplate> 
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel> 
    </ItemsControl> 
<Style  x:Key="ElementThumbVMDataTemplateStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter"> 
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"  Value="{Binding CanvasLeft,Mode=TwoWay}" /> 
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"  Value="{Binding CanvasTop,Mode=TwoWay}" />             </Style >
```

And something like this for Node DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Node}"> 
                <kw:ElementThumb Canvas.Left="{Binding CanvasLeft,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                 Canvas.Top="{Binding CanvasTop,Mode=TwoWay}"> 
                </kw:ElementThumb> 
            </DataTemplate>
```

Canvasleft and CanvasTop are properties that exist in Node and also ElementThumb classes.

Comment: Offside: `INotifyPropertyChanged` and auto-imp properties are an odd combination.

Comment: I Would implement that as soon as i need, but the problem here is another thing.

Answer (score 0):

Placing an object of the type you are creating a DataTemplate for inside the DataTemplate itself is quite pointless. DataTemplates are there for the creation of a visual representation of your data, so you first need a concept of how you want to visualize your Nodes and Connections.

Comment: I can share more of that implementation if its required.